# Function argument persisting through multiple calls

Tags: python

Why does the errors argument persist across successive function calls?  Shouldn't it be reset to `[]` since no parameter was specified?

```
def test(errors=[]):
    errors.append('hello')
    return errors


print(test()) # ['hello']
print(test()) # ['hello', 'hello']
```

Comment: This is a classical python problem that has come up many times. Refer to above comment.

Comment: If only that question's accepted answer wasn't terrible.